# Using ECDSA instead of RSA for encrypting and decrypting integer

Tags: cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I want to use ECDSA instead of RSA for encrypting and decrypting integer number. Ususally ECDSA is used for digital signature. But it's possible **to transform algorthm of digital signature**: use signature generation for decryption, signature verification for encryption. I have a problem with transforming algorithm like that.

**I want to know, what should encryption-function and decryption-function do.**

P.S.: Please, don't suggest me to use ECDH and ECIES. It's not what I need. I need ECDSA work exactly like RSA: get integer, encrypt it to another integer and decrypt this integer.

Comment: If you want encryption with elliptic curves, then you should use ECIES.

Comment: 1) Why do you need ECDSA instead of ECIES? 2) I remember cryptographers abusing DSA to achieve encryption, but that was only to make a point about legislation that forbids encryption but allows signatures. Nobody sane would actually use that. 3) There is no generic way to turn a signature algorithm into an encryption algorithm. It particular it's possible to construct signatures from hashes but it has been shown that it's impossible to construct asymmetric encryption from hashes.